# Get value of a svelte nested custom store, is inside another custom store

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

Based on [this REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/1a1f438d1e7446bbb61586b6892ca4ec?version=3.31.2) I've made. I created two svelte custom store like this :

```js
<script>
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";
    
    var store1;
    const {subscribe:subscribe_store1, set:set_store1, update:update_store1} = writable(store1)
    const Store1 = {
        subscribe:subscribe_store1,
        customfunction1:CustomFunction1
    }
    
    function CustomFunction1(str){set_store1(str)}
    
    
    
    var store2;
    const {subscribe:subscribe_store2, set:set_store2, update:update_store2} = writable(store1)
    const Store2 = {
        subscribe:subscribe_store2,
        customfunction2:CustomFunction2
    }
    
    function CustomFunction2(str){set_store2(str)}
    
    
    Store1.customfunction1("is 1!")
    Store2.customfunction2("is 2!")
</script>

<h1>Store1 : {$Store1}</h1>
<h2>Store2 : {$Store2}</h2>
```

How can I access the value of $Store2 with Store1 ? I only found [this solution](https://svelte.dev/repl/e18397a7c46544e08cd7e76efa23c583?version=3.31.2) but it's kind of annoying having to import and call the `get` function all the time

EDIT : And it's not reactive...

```js
import {writable, get} from "svelte/store"

...

const Store2 = {
   subscribe:subscribe_store2,
   Store1:Store1,
   customfunction2:CustomFunction2
}

...

<h3>{get({Store2.Store1)}</h3>
```

If you have a better way of doing it, I'll take it.

EDIT : If you have something working, I'll definitely take it.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I have found to work assuming Store1 is reactive

```html
$: store1 = Store2.Store1

<h3>{$store1}</h3>
```